# Rails 4 Raw SQL Server Queries - Still Incredibly Slow Using .execute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, performance, optimization

I have a Rails 4 application that executes many different SQL Server Queries. Most return less than 1,000 rows, and the page loads pretty quickly in the browser. No issues there.

However, I have this one monster query that returns 56,000 rows. It has to return all 56k, no questions asked. Sure it can use pagination, but that's not going to solve the issue of a slow page load.

Note that this is a remote SQL server we use in-house.

What I've tried so far:

using `find_by_sql` in a method definition which is defined in a model, then calling that in the controller. Ie,

`@query = Client.closed_trouble_tickets`

Then iterate through `@query` in the view. That works okay for the < 1,000 row queries. When I try that approach for the 56k rows, the page can take close to two minutes to load. Unacceptable.

What I've tried for this 56k one:

```
@records = []

Client.connection.select_all(Client.send(:sanitize_sql_array, 
["SQL QUERY HERE FOR 56,000 ROWS"])).each do |record|

    @records << { a_name: record["OneColumn"], b_name: record["TwoColumn"] ... }

end
```

This is a bit faster, but still an acceptable page-load time (maybe 60 seconds instead of 90+). When I run the 56k query in SQL Server Management Studio, it is instant.

I also tried using a setup of this nature, but the page-load speed was similar to above:

```
def self.execute_statement(sql)
    results = Client.connection.execute(sql)
    if results.present?
        return results
    else
        return nil
    end
end
```

What can I do to speed this up?

Comment: I had a similar situation where I needed to return 100,000 records and found integrating elastic search into my app made it 2340928340 times faster when doing queries since it's basically indexing everything and keeping its own database.  I'd say your two best options are Redis and ElasticSearch.  Redis will store everything in memory making things like lookups near instant.  Are you sure the database is taking a long time fetching the data or is it the view that is eating up the time?

Comment: Nice, will look into those now and report back. 'Are you sure', well, no, I did a couple Benchmarks last week and the return time wasn't too bad from what I recall. That being said, I'm allmost certain it's the query being used in the view. And as stated, the query runs fine in SQL Server Management studio.

Comment: I think what you are seeing is a fast query by your database in Rails however "find_by_sql"  returns an array of active-record objects.  These objects (when in thousands) decimate performance.  Since I don't know your query I cant give you more advice but if the query needs to remain as is and return objects I think ElasticSearch would be far better since you could ask for "results" (which are elastic-search objects) instead of "records"(active-record objects).

Comment: Gist here of query: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d65c4f304b88a12570f3330ebc847344

Comment: Looks like the issue lies with appending objects into your records array.  This is instantiating a new object for each and thus crushing the garbage collector.  Either use elastic search as proposed or change your query to rely on Rails functions such as "ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_values(sql query)  which returns an array of values unparsed thus never instantiating active record objects.  You'd then look to instantiate only the objects within the page offset returned as activerecord objects if needed.

Comment: Right on. I appreciate your detailed replies. Will report back here!